# How to pass a POJO as argument from JSF backing bean to JWS using jnlp?

Tags: jsf, jnlp, pojo, backing-beans

Is it possible to pass a POJO serialized object, from a JSF backing bean to a Java Web Start application using jnlp?

I'm not sure if I am Googling the right thing or not, but there seems to be little information on argument passing in jnlp.

Comment: If you 'manually' serialize and de-serialize it should work perfectly if you pass that as a jws startup parameter. Or retrieve it via a webservice

Comment: Thanks Kukeltje; the object uncompressed is 7 meg so passing as a parameter is not really possible. I don't know much about web services, so will have to look into that.